What could cause a DC fan to burn out?
I have participated in the electronical development of a device that has been sold in approximately 10,000 units. The device includes a DC fan.  About 1% of these units have experienced fan burnout. When I apply 5V to one of the burned-out fans, it tries to spin briefly but stops immediately.
Here is the datasheet of the fan.
Here is the schematic:


The fan's input voltage is 5V, supplied by a DC-DC converter.
The PWM input is generated by a microcontroller with a 3.3V output.
The LOCKD signal provides speed information from the fan.

L2 was added for EMC reasons. I am considering whether I should add a flyback diode across it. Could the inductance current cause large voltage spikes when the 5V supply is shut off?
Additionally, if some of you have already experienced this issue, what other factors could cause the fan to fail?

What is the part number and voltage and current info for the fan?

So that's a connector for connecting the fan? What exact part number is L2? Why do you have 10nF capacitor on MCU PWM output? Also why 10nF on fan LOCKD signal? You should maybe provide detailed fan datasheet and extend those signals to power supply and MCU.

Is there information about ambient temperature vs. life expectancy in the datasheet? What is the expected operating temperature range?

Where are your test results? DMM, DSO plots?   Is this a Delta or Nidec fan? datasheet pls.

model # pls   if no datasheet

Still no p/n?  or update on your test results?  "Thank you for your support !"

Sorry I was away yesterday, I have added the datasheet of the fan

Does the blade in a faulty fan turn as freely as a new fan if you blow air at in a controlled fashion (for example, with another fan)? That model appears to have a stall/halt/restart function in the controller IC.

The fan can spin if I blow on it (powered or not), but it stops spinning once I stop.

Usually DC fans die from heat. This happens either from something blocking the coil or an over voltage or over current condition.
There could be a large LC filter with the ferrite and the capacitors. Typically fan's don't need bypass capacitors unless there is a lot of ripple. Also, if t he fan is rated for 5V and there is really 220Ω it's likely that the voltage supply for the fan is dropping it below the voltage that the fan is rated for and that could be causing issues.
Test the rail at C8577 with an oscilloscope and see what happens when the fan shuts off and what it looks like during normal operation. If you see a spike above what the fan is rated for, this could be affecting the liftime of the fan.
Also check to see if the fan is getting hot, put it on a normal bench supply without the filter and see if it get's hot vs the one in the circuit above.

I suspect the "220 ohms" is the impedance of the bead at the stated frequency of 100MHz. (not DC resistance)

@rohmeooo It must be. That's an explicit notation for it. Most often you just se 220R and it means the same thing, as that's not a resistor. The DCR of the bead should be in the order of few tens of milliohms.

OK thank you I will check if there are spikes above 5 V on this pin

No, I don't see spikes on C8577

The fan is not "burned out" if it spins briefly.  It seems more likely that the microcontroller has decided to shut it off.  The first thing to look at would be the FAN_LOCKD signal to make sure nothing unexpected is happening there.

Actually, I tried to power on the fan without the use of the microcontroller, and it did not spin. If I apply 5V, it spins for 1 s and then stops. If I try it on another fan, it works perfectly

It seems you could have a resonance between "5L2" and "C8577"/"CP178", which would cause the voltage to rise beyond 5V on load steps, power on, etc.
Otherwise, be mindful that most components don't like being powered through their "IO" (here, the PWM and FAN1_LOCKD) signal when 5V is not provided. So make sure the power is up before those signals are driven or even pulled up through a pullup resistor.
Final thing is make sure the PWM signal the motor sees is "fast". I can't say exactly how fast, but sometimes a slow edge can cause electronics to lock up or otherwise suffer.
That's all i can think of, electrically. There's always mechanical issues like vibration or chemistry.

From where would this resonance arise? It's a ferrite bead after all, not an inductor. An LC filter with step loads could need some damping, but this should work.

@Justme, the ferrite bead is exactly an inductor... it's a more "traditional" inductor at low frequencies and the inductance drops and ohmic/lossy resistance increases at a certain point, but it is for sure an inductor.    see: https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/articles/ferrite-beads-demystified.html

Yes, it would have something like 1..2 uH at 1 to 10 MHz. Resonating with the unknown 100nF cap, but also damped by the 10uF lossy electrolytic. And at what frequencies would the fan pull current, at few tens of Hz instead of 1 MHz?

@Justme, i agree; didn't notice the 10uF appears to be polarized and thus likely a lossy electrolytic.  So, pretty unlikely it resonates, but it's worth a scope capture IMO.  And it doesn't matter what frequencies the fan pulls current, if it pulls a step or impulse, it will drive the resonance and overshoot, if only once and without additional gain.  Similarly on turn-on, if the 5V turns on quickly enough (fast edge like a step) it will drive the resonance and overshoot, again, if only once.
